# Firebase || Reference error : app is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase

I wanted to access app in the second script, but I got an undefined error.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="module">
    import {
      initializeApp
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
    import {
      getFirestore,
      collection,
      getDocs
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore.js";
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "**********",
      authDomain: "**",
      projectId: "*"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    console.log(app);
  </script>
  <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

I am just using a `console.log(app)` in the second script tag.

I am also using defer to delay.
Below is the output on the console.

[image: Console output]

Comment: Don't use const in this case, it will be local scoped. Use var.